# What Model Year is Magic Chef Oven Model #3520SRW?

Tags: oven

What Model Year is Magic Chef Oven Model #3520SRW?

Serial number: 29486821MB

Electric range. Manufactured in Cleveland, TN 37311, per label.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the always useful [Appliance 411](http://www.appliance411.com/service/date-code.php):

**January 1995**

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Problem is at the destination site. Sometimes working, sometimes *very* slow, sometimes not at all. The link is correct.